# Displaying QR Code to a PDF stream, Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, qr-code, dompdf

Hello im trying to display a QR Code(generated by https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode) on to a pdf file(generated by https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/tree/0.4)

here are my codes:

routes.php

> $pdf = PDF::loadView('emails.applicationform');
>
> return $pdf->stream();

emails/applicationformpdf.blade.php

> {{QrCode::size(200)->generate('hello')}}

P.S. I can confirm that i can out text and certain images to the pdf stream. i have tried to use

> $pdf->download('something.pdf');

as well in the routes.php file but with no luck. Does anyone know a way to work around this?

EDIT:
There are three formats available for the qr code but only svg renders properly. The other two formats outputs the following.
PNG:

```
�PNG  IHDR��":9�JIDATx���A��0@��0�?r��x�B�Y�S�N�6�|��?������}<��H���H���H���H���H���H���H���H���H���H���H���H���H���H���H���H���H���H�����^;S9��z��w���ܻ:7�bl�"!,�"!,�"q�Tx�M+#SتIm�.��{ʊEBX$�EBX$�Eb�Tx57�ܹ6�8w=��� +  a�  a����;�}�s��`V,�"!,�"!,�>��w�^�cX�H���H���H�8�?Ou��;��Y�H���H���H�� �����U���|�c<���KX$�EBX$�E��1�Ss��E�X$�EBX$�EBX$N|^��_�uO�{�hw�Y�H���H���H��+�s�n�s�i��X$�EBX$�EBX$�O�W�߈��ʽ;���j�"!,�"!,�"�����;��>q��&ⅎ� �AX$�EBX$�E�Ľ���]7'�z�G�b�   a� a��ԩp��{�����N�V,�"!,�"!,'�A�Y5�}7u�]s{��g�++    a�  a����+������l{�|7ǊEBX$�EBX$�Eb�Tx���#��=?q��ӥ���H���H�ĉS��V�Z3�{�Ł>��9��H���H�ķO�w�A��s>b��b�   a�  a�8q*����w���kn��{MʊEBX$�EBX$�Eb�T�}W�?#����w�����O�1�EBX$�EBX$��y�D�X$�EBX$�EBX$�EBX$�EBX$�EBX$�EBX$�EBX$�EBX$�EBX$�EBX$�EBX$�EBX$�EBX$�EBX$�EBX$�EBX$�EBX$�E���w�D�RIEND�B`�
```

EPS:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0 %%BoundingBox: 0 0 200 200 /F { rectfill } def 1.000000 setgray 0 0 200 200 F 0.000000 setgray 37 163 6 6 F 43 163 6 6 F 49 163 6 6 F 55 163 6 6 F 61 163 6 6 F 67 163 6 6 F 73 163 6 6 F 91 163 6 6 F 103 163 6 6 F 109 163 6 6 F 121 163 6 6 F 127 163 6 6 F 133 163 6 6 F 139 163 6 6 F 145 163 6 6 F 151 163 6 6 F 157 163 6 6 F 37 157 6 6 F 73 157 6 6 F 85 157 6 6 F 91 157 6 6 F 103 157 6 6 F 121 157 6 6 F 157 157 6 6 F 37 151 6 6 F 49 151 6 6 F 55 151 6 6 F 61 151 6 6 F 73 151 6 6 F 85 151 6 6 F 91 151 6 6 F 109 151 6 6 F 121 151 6 6 F 133 151 6 6 F 139 151 6 6 F 145 151 6 6 F 157 151 6 6 F 37 145 6 6 F 49 145 6 6 F 55 145 6 6 F 61 145 6 6 F 73 145 6 6 F 91 145 6 6 F 103 145 6 6 F 121 145 6 6 F 133 145 6 6 F 139 145 6 6 F 145 145 6 6 F 157 145 6 6 F 37 139 6 6 F 49 139 6 6 F 55 139 6 6 F 61 139 6 6 F 73 139 6 6 F 85 139 6 6 F 109 139 6 6 F 121 139 6 6 F 133 139 6 6 F 139 139 6 6 F 145 139 6 6 F 157 139 6 6 F 37 133 6 6 F 73 133 6 6 F 85 133 6 6 F 103 133 6 6 F 109 133 6 6 F 121 133 6 6 F 157 133 6 6 F 37 127 6 6 F 43 127 6 6 F 49 127 6 6 F 55 127 6 6 F 61 127 6 6 F 67 127 6 6 F 73 127 6 6 F 85 127 6 6 F 97 127 6 6 F 109 127 6 6 F 121 127 6 6 F 127 127 6 6 F 133 127 6 6 F 139 127 6 6 F 145 127 6 6 F 151 127 6 6 F 157 127 6 6 F 85 121 6 6 F 91 121 6 6 F 97 121 6 6 F 103 121 6 6 F 109 121 6 6 F 37 115 6 6 F 43 115 6 6 F 55 115 6 6 F 73 115 6 6 F 79 115 6 6 F 91 115 6 6 F 97 115 6 6 F 121 115 6 6 F 127 115 6 6 F 133 115 6 6 F 145 115 6 6 F 151 115 6 6 F 43 109 6 6 F 49 109 6 6 F 55 109 6 6 F 61 109 6 6 F 67 109 6 6 F 79 109 6 6 F 85 109 6 6 F 91 109 6 6 F 121 109 6 6 F 151 109 6 6 F 157 109 6 6 F 49 103 6 6 F 55 103 6 6 F 67 103 6 6 F 73 103 6 6 F 79 103 6 6 F 85 103 6 6 F 97 103 6 6 F 109 103 6 6 F 115 103 6 6 F 139 103 6 6 F 145 103 6 6 F 157 103 6 6 F 55 97 6 6 F 67 97 6 6 F 85 97 6 6 F 103 97 6 6 F 139 97 6 6 F 151 97 6 6 F 157 97 6 6 F 61 91 6 6 F 73 91 6 6 F 79 91 6 6 F 91 91 6 6 F 97 91 6 6 F 109 91 6 6 F 121 91 6 6 F 133 91 6 6 F 85 85 6 6 F 91 85 6 6 F 97 85 6 6 F 103 85 6 6 F 127 85 6 6 F 133 85 6 6 F 145 85 6 6 F 157 85 6 6 F 37 79 6 6 F 43 79 6 6 F 49 79 6 6 F 55 79 6 6 F 61 79 6 6 F 67 79 6 6 F 73 79 6 6 F 85 79 6 6 F 91 79 6 6 F 97 79 6 6 F 115 79 6 6 F 127 79 6 6 F 139 79 6 6 F 145 79 6 6 F 151 79 6 6 F 37 73 6 6 F 73 73 6 6 F 91 73 6 6 F 97 73 6 6 F 103 73 6 6 F 109 73 6 6 F 115 73 6 6 F 127 73 6 6 F 133 73 6 6 F 37 67 6 6 F 49 67 6 6 F 55 67 6 6 F 61 67 6 6 F 73 67 6 6 F 91 67 6 6 F 103 67 6 6 F 121 67 6 6 F 127 67 6 6 F 133 67 6 6 F 157 67 6 6 F 37 61 6 6 F 49 61 6 6 F 55 61 6 6 F 61 61 6 6 F 73 61 6 6 F 85 61 6 6 F 97 61 6 6 F 103 61 6 6 F 127 61 6 6 F 139 61 6 6 F 145 61 6 6 F 151 61 6 6 F 157 61 6 6 F 37 55 6 6 F 49 55 6 6 F 55 55 6 6 F 61 55 6 6 F 73 55 6 6 F 91 55 6 6 F 97 55 6 6 F 109 55 6 6 F 133 55 6 6 F 145 55 6 6 F 157 55 6 6 F 37 49 6 6 F 73 49 6 6 F 85 49 6 6 F 91 49 6 6 F 97 49 6 6 F 115 49 6 6 F 121 49 6 6 F 37 43 6 6 F 43 43 6 6 F 49 43 6 6 F 55 43 6 6 F 61 43 6 6 F 67 43 6 6 F 73 43 6 6 F 85 43 6 6 F 97 43 6 6 F 103 43 6 6 F 109 43 6 6 F 127 43 6 6 F 139 43 6 6 F 151 43 6 6 F
```

I have tried putting the png in an img tag and put the qr code as the source but with no luck.

Comment: Can you generate the QR code into "normal" view? QrCode must generate the image and HTML that DomPdf must convert into PDF.

Comment: yes i have tried to display it in a normal html page and it worked. only when i put it in a pdf that it does not render. i suspect that maybe its because of an svg file type but if i tried the other formats(png, eps) a bunch of weird symbols show up.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick solution

```
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->size(100)->generate('Make me into an QrCode!')) }} ">
```

Source [github](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/194)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I was able to resolve my problem by saving the qr code in a folder as .png and called it from there.

Comment: This is actually solve my problems also, thanks for suggesting this, it seems like generating qrcode altogether on the fly of creating pdf doesn't really work, you need to generate beforehand the qrcode in some places and call it from there. Thanks!